# "Crimson Skies " for Windows 7

Tags: backwards-compatibility, crimson-skies

I had a blast playing Microsofts computer game "Crimson Skies", but that was on a computer that had XP Pro as it's OS. When Win7 came out and I transferred from old to new it was un-playable. So, has anyone been able to get this game to play on any of the post XP computer systems? And if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can install 1.02 patch and then download a fix From:

http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Crimson_Skies#Modern_hardware_support